# How to copy database backup (created by maintenance plans) files to remote machine

Tags: sql-server, configuration, database-administration, system-administration, maintenance-plan

I would like to copy backup files after MS SQL Server maintenance plan to a new shared folder in another server.
How to do that??

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: The following link talk about my problem
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldisasterrecovery/thread/21af8f0f-f45d-4bc0-b1e5-ab9de860d0b5/
but i don't understand the solution steps
*Go to BIDS--> create a New project -- > Open the project.

In solution explorer you can see "SSIS packages" folder --> Right click on the folder

Select "Add existing package"

Mention the servername & Authentication mode in the window then you can select the maintainence plan you have created.*

Comment: You need to phrase your question in such a way that allows us to explain the answer. If all we do is regurgitate/paraphrase what the reference states, how will we know if that will help you any better? We won't. We need to understand more context about what you didn't understand.

Comment: I don't know what is BIDS,so I could not understand all the steps.Is this block represent solution for my problem??

Comment: I found many keys but could not apply any one of them

1-Create batch file and add to scheduled task (But I don't know how to write it)
2-Use SQL command xcopy to copy backup files (but the names is autmatically generated,how could i know the files that are not copied in my shared folder)

Comment: +1 Why was this question downvoted? This is not so trivial question with ready and searchable answer since: 1) the file name of backup created by maintenance is unknown beforehand (it is something like `DBName_backup_2013_10_08_014242_1520978.bak` 2)There is a need to purge older target files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I used

1- Create batch file with robocopy command

```
ROBOCOPY C:\backfolder \\sharedserver\c$\backupcopy *.bak /S /purge
```

2- Add new task to the task scheduler to run every day after the maintenance plan time
Controlpanel >> Administrative tools >> Task Scheduler then add new task to run the batch file.